# Powershell | Can't Figure Out Trap Function

Tags: powershell

Ok i'm at a loss >.> I have tried try/catch and trap function and it's wont catch this error...

```
# Adjustable Variables
$Computers_Path = ".\Compuers.txt"
$Log_Path = ".\Log.txt"

# Script Specific Variables


# Validate Adjustable Variables
TRAP { Write-Host "Unable to locate list of computer names at $Computers_Path"; Continue; }
$Computers = Get-Content $Computers_Path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Computers = Get-Content $Computers_Path -ea stop
```

this lets the `trap` catch the exception.

Comment: Not exactly what i was hoping for but it does work, seems to repeat the error message 3 times, and if i add "Break" instead of "Continue" still displays the ugly @$$ error.

Comment: @user1451070 try using `Return`.

Comment: Thank you that seems to have done the trick. May I inquire where you learned about the "-ea" command and exactly what it is? Spent a few hours googleing error handling techniques and yet to see that particular command.

Comment: `ea` is an alias for `ErrorAction`. Read here some interesting info: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/09/hey-scripting-guy-march-9-2010.aspx

Comment: Still seems like a bug that Trap and try/catch can't catch it without that considering the purpose of those commands.